# TauDEM Model Availability

Tags: modelbuilder, hydrology, taudem

I'm trying to find the TauDEM Model Builder Models toolbox.

I'm teaching myself how to use TauDEM to delineate watersheds. After running through some examples I started putting the modules together in Model Builder. Before I finished, I realized that someone may have already done this and I found exactly what I was building on [pages 10-11](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/TauDEM5DelineatingASingleWatershed.pdf) on David Tarboton's website (developer of TauDEM). However, the model that is referenced as available to download no longer seems available.

[This site](http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads2.html) has downloads for the scripts and individual tools, but not the full model builder geoprocessing tool. Anyone know if this is available anywhere? If not, I will

Comment: Did you also download the **ArcGIS toolbox and Python Scripts (Developed for ArcGIS 10.0 or higher)** mentioned on that page?

Comment: I did, but did not find the model building tool described in the pdf. Am I missing something?  I'm trying to recreate it from the screenshot but am having problems :-/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This modelbuilder toolbox is available on the version 5.1.2 download page in Previous Versions in TauDEM at http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/downloads5.1.html.

I have not been able to get this working properly for later versions and have given up.  I have not been able to resolve problems related to where input files are saved and how they are named and the automatic population of default names that TauDEM uses conflicting with how model builder treats names.  I have had trouble properly linking output to inputs.

I tried again today and the toobox for the current version of TauDEM is at http://hydrology.usu.edu/taudem/taudem5/TauDEMModels_8_4_18.tbx.  However moved outlets are not properly connected in this workflow and some file names may be hard coded.

As a result, if I need to automate a sequence of TauDEM functions, I do not use model builder.  I instead use a batch file.  The batch file commands to execute the sequence that the model builder workflow implements are:

```
mpiexec -n 8 pitremove -z Logan.tif -fel Loganfel.tif
mpiexec -n 8 D8FlowDir -fel Loganfel.tif -p Loganp.tif -sd8 Logansd8.tif
mpiexec -n 8 AreaD8 -p Loganp.tif -ad8 Loganad8.tif
mpiexec -n 8 Threshold -ssa Loganad8.tif -src Logansrc.tif -thresh 100
mpiexec -n 8 MoveOutletsToStreams -p Loganp.tif -src Logansrc.tif -o Outlet.shp -om Logansrc_Outletmv.shp -md 50
mpiexec -n 8 PeukerDouglas -fel loganfel.tif -ss Loganss.tif -par 0.4 0.1 0.05
mpiexec -n 8 AreaD8 -p loganp.tif -ad8 Loganssa.tif -wg Loganss.tif
mpiexec -n 8 Threshold -ssa Loganssa.tif -src Logansrc1.tif -thresh 50
mpiexec -n 8 StreamNet -fel Loganfel.tif -p loganp.tif -ad8 Loganad8.tif -src Loganssa.tif -ord Loganord.tif -tree Logantree.txt -coord Logancoord.txt -net Logannet.shp -w Loganw.tif -sw
```

While not quite as elegant or flexible, this does get the job done.

Comment: Thanks David, I’ll go with the batch file solution. I appreciate you sharing!